# Render directive after javascript-adding on page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a web-page with angular application, angular-directive, controller, and other javascript-functions. One from this functions is adding html-code on page. This html contains one from my angular directives. But angular doesn't render directive's template if it was added dynamically. How to render this derictive in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Here is nice example of dynamically adding html code with included directive (alert).

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ftfish/KyEr3/)

The general idea is to `$compile` your html code. Check in example.